# How do you make a batch file check for duplicate batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do you check for already existing batch files in batch script?
I'm working on a batch RPG game where you can log in or create an account. I have successfully been able to set up a code that notifies the user when the username has a space in it, and how it can't be used, but I'm stumped at how it could be done to check for a duplicate batch file. For example, I already have a username called "Test", and I would like to make another username called "Test"...

Here is a copy of my code for the no spaces script:

```
:createuser
echo.
echo What would you like your Username to be?
set /p username1= 
set v1f=0

:checkforspaces
set x=!v1f!
set Letter%v1f%=!username1:~%x%,1!
if "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU " " (
echo.
echo.
echo Sorry you cant use spaces in your Username.
pause>nul
goto entergame
)
if NOT "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU "" (
set /a v1f=%v1f%+1
goto checkforspaces
)
echo.
echo What would you like your Password to be?
set /p password1= 
goto DATA_VALUES
```

[image: And here is an image of the Game:]

Comment: Welcome to this site for [professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).      Tags generally display a short description as you type or click on them. Tags  can help direct the right (or wrong) people to your question.  (To professional business application programmers, RPG is a language.)

Answer (score 1):

To check for spaces in `var`:

```
echo %var%|find " " >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo no spaces) else (echo spaces found)
```

to check whether the filename `var` exists:

```
if exist %var%.ext (echo file %var%.ext exists) else (echo file %var%.ext not found)
```

btw - an easy-peasy game-save routine is

```
set>%var%.ext
```

and reload is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%var%.ext) do set %%a
```

note that `var` above can be any variable-name and `.ext` your chosen file extension.